# How do I reference MVC Area from one assembly into another assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-areas

Following on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478263/how-can-a-large-mvc-4-application-be-divided-to-multiple-smaller-applications) and I hope that doesn't conflict with SO policy or usage guidelines.

I previously had a large MVC project that I took a specific area out it and put it into a separate project.

My question is:
There are some areas in the first (previously large) app that can be included (by using statements) in the classes on the second (new) app. Why are some areas can be referenced in the new assembly and some other areas can't?

Edit: Generally some namespaces are recognized by the new app while others are not. This is not specific to a particular area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways depending on your needs.

Here are a few simple methods to breakup the pieces:

- Use the [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) to package your views, as described [here](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911006/asp-net-mvc-4-areas-in-separate-projects-not-working-view-not-found)
- Use a [portable area](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) or what's built-in to Visual Studio as described [here](http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/06/mvc-portable-areas/) or [here](http://codesnob.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/mvc-area-in-an-external-assembly/)

There are more, but this should get you started quickest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helpful links. For those who encounter the same problem, the link in therewillbesnacks' answer is a good step by step guide on how to start.

Comment: The RazorGenerator project has moved to GitHub. https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator